# C# return multiples of a number in a number and the remainder?

Tags: c#

I want to find all multiples of 3 given a certain number, and also find the remainder.

So for example:

Given the number 10 : multiples of 3 = {3;6;9} + remainder = 1

Given the number 11 : multiples of 3 = {3;6;9} + remainder = 2

The algorithm I have so far (but not code) goes like this:

1. Check if X is a multiple of 3 - Yes - return multiples (no remainder);
2. No? is x-1 a multiple of 3 - Yes - return multiples (1 remainder);
3. No? is x-2 a multiple of 3 - Yes - return multples (2 remainder);

Is there a better way to do this, using less code?

Edit: 2 more things, I'm only looking for 3 - so this could be a const. Also any number smaller than 3: 2, 1 and 0 - I don't mind having additional logic for that.

Comment: This is such low-hanging fruit, I'm not surprised to see 5 answers in 1 minute. Way to pitch a slow one, @JL.!

Comment: @JesseSmith Questions like this are like catnip to programmers I think - we just can't resist answering them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) (`/`) and [modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) (`%`) are your friends here:

```
var multiples = num / 3;
var remainder = num % 3;
```

Comment: That suprises me considering the way your question is worded. I'm confused now!

Comment: @F.B.tenKate - Sure, nothing like a complete solution, but OP seems to have been missing some basic building blocks. Sometimes our job is to teach a man how to fish...

Comment: Agreed, I gave the same answer you did (deleted it by now since like 9 others did the same) but ye, the way he worded his question Leppie's question is the most complete. Regardless it's good to teach a guy to Fish... or... in this case, Math.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate - I think, in this case - C# operators ;)

Answer (score 13):

```
IEnumerable<int> Foo(int n, int k)
{
  int m = k;
  while (m <= n)
  {
    yield return m;
    m += k;
  }

  yield return m - n;
}
```

Comment: Ye, this answer seems the nicest to be honest (after reading the question 5 times :x)

Answer (score 4):

x = given number
y = loop number

have y loop from 0 to x while increasing it by 3 every time.
if y > x then the remender is (x-(y-3))

Comment: Wow, I really hope no one does this.

Comment: Heh, I just gave the same, IMO what the OP is asking for :)

Comment: @F.B.tenKate why? he want's all number between 0 and x that are multiple of 3 and the remainder

Comment: Because it's very CPU intensive and the way to do exactly what the OP is asking for us using the Divide and Modulus functions baked into .NET

Comment: @F.B.tenKate How doesn't want the **count** of numbers - he wants the **list** of numbers.

Comment: @Leppie you're actually right... Not the easiest question to read though (in my defense)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the divider  /  and the modulus %

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx

```
10 / 3 = 3
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

```
10 % 3 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 10;
int divisor = 3;

List<int> numbers;

// Find all the numbers by incrementing i by the divisor.
for(int i = 0; i < number; i += divisor)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}

// Find the remainder using modulus operator.
int remainder = number % divisor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your exact output

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 10;
        int divisor = 3;

        if(num<divisor)
            Console.Write(num + " is less than " + divisor);

        Console.Write("Given the number " + num + " : multiples of " + divisor + " = {");

        for (int i = divisor; i < num; i+=divisor)
            Console.Write((i!=3) ? ";"+i : i.ToString());

        Console.Write("} + remainder = " + num%divisor);

    }
```

**Output**

`Given the number 10 : multiples of 3 = {3;6;9} + remainder = 1`

and checks if input is less than divisor

Comment: I find it odd, that you'd create a variable for `10`, making it easily interchangeable with any other number, but not for `3`. Just saying.

Comment: just hammered it out quickly, there ya go

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *enumerate* the output values

```
  public static IEnumerable<int> GetMultiples(int value, int divisor) {
    // Be care of negative and zero values...
    if ((value <= 0) || (divisor <= 0))
      yield break;

    // Multiplications
    for (int i = 1; i <= value / divisor; ++i)
      yield return i * divisor;

    // Finally, let's return remainder if it's non-zero
    if ((value % divisor) != 0)
      yield return value % divisor;
  }

  ...

  foreach(int item in GetMultiples(10, 3)) { // item will be 3, 6, 9, 1
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator modulo

```
%
```

But is very slowly if you use a lot...

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you want:

```
            int num;
            Console.WriteLine("give me a number equal or above 3!");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out num);
            int i = 0;
            List<int> nums = new List<int>();
            i += 3;
            while (i <= num)
            {
                nums.Add(i);
                i += 3;
            }

            Console.Write("Numbers are: ");
            foreach (int y in nums)
            {
                Console.Write(y + " , ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The remainder is " + (num - nums[nums.Count - 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't LINQ built for EXACTLY for this?

```
IEnumerable<int> GetMultiples(int max)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, max / 3)
                     .Select(p => p * 3)
                     .Concat((max %= 3) == 0 ? new int[0] : new int[] { max });
}
```